# Why can enums be a type arguments in dart?

Tags: dart, enums

I have noticed that generic methods can have type arguments which are enums which does not make sense to me a type arguments indicate the type of object. So why can enums be used a type?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: @jamesdlin apologies for the late response. For example for the DropdownButton Class in the flutter library it states "The type T is the type of the value that each dropdown item represents. All the entries in a given menu must represent values with consistent types. Typically, an enum is used". The link to the documentation is https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum` specifies a type just like any other type declaration, and you specify types to make use of static-type-checking.

```dart
enum Direction { north, east, south, west }

void main() {
  Direction d = Direction.north;
  d = 42; // Error.  Cannot assign an `int` to a `Direction`.
  int i = Direction.west; // Error.  Cannot assign a `Direction` to an `int`.
}
```

Since `enum` declares a type, there's no reason why `enum` types shouldn't be allowed as type arguments for generics, just like for any other type.